# query data in mysql using a date in a datetime column

Tags: mysql

I want to query data in mysql. The problem is the column is datetime(dpost) and i will use a date in the where clause.

```
SELECT * FROM `uid1000_qposts` WHERE `dpost`="2011-12-06"
```

this query doesn't return any results. Is there any possible way I can query data using date against a datetime column?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM `uid1000_qposts` WHERE date(`dpost`) = '2011-12-06'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `uid1000_qposts` WHERE DATE_FORMAT(dpost,'%Y-%m-%d')='2011-12-06'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE dpost between "2011-12-06 00:00:00" and "2011-12-06 23:59:59"
```

Another possibilities is using

```
DATE_FORMAT(dpost,'%Y-%m-%d')="2011-12-06"
```

but is not recommended,
as it won't make use on any index (even there is)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `uid1000_qposts` WHERE date(`dpost`) = '2011-12-06'
```